# Invalid grant_type YouTube api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, youtube-api

I'm trying to exchange the authorization code for an access token. I'm using the `HttpClient` in ASP.NET to make a post request:

```
var clientId = "clientid";
var redirectUri = "http://localhost:65148/Welcome";
var clientSecret = "clientsecret";

if (code != null)
{
    //Lets exchange the code for a access token
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "code", code },
            { "client_id", clientId },
            { "client_secret", clientSecret },
            { "redirect_uri", redirectUri },
            { "grant_type", code }
        };


        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
        var response = await client.PostAsync("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", content);
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var value = Json(new { data = responseString });
        return value;
    }

}
```

But when I run this, I get a error message:

```
{
    "error" : "invalid_request",
    "error_description" : "Invalid grant_type:4/AlxtyFqHeOiTC32THJgipkUWtHBO27GqFfgOoOCG9wE"
}
```

I don't know why I'm getting this.

Comment: what is the value of the code variable?  (that represents your 'grant_type' param which is usually set to 'password')

Comment: @user1821052: Check my error message. After grant_type: you have the code.

Comment: ok I see - looks like you are setting the variable code to both the "code" and the "grant_type".   Try setting "grant_type" to the string 'password'

Comment: @user1821052: According to the documentation, the grant_type should be the authorization code: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps#Obtaining_Access_Tokens

Comment: ahh - they are asking it to be set to the literal string 'authorization_code'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the link you provided it states the `grant_type` should be set to **authorization_code**.   I can see this being confusing (perhaps it should be the value of code?) but then later in the example it *is* clarified to be a string literal of 'authorization_code'.

```
A sample request is displayed below:

POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: accounts.google.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

code=4/ux5gNj-_mIu4DOD_gNZdjX9EtOFf&
client_id=1084945748469-eg34imk572gdhu83gj5p0an9fut6urp5.apps.googleusercontent.com&
client_secret=hDBmMRhz7eJRsM9Z2q1oFBSe&
redirect_uri=http://localhost/oauth2callback&
**grant_type=authorization_code**
```

Perhaps more interestingly, the `grant_type` is a standard for OAuth 2.0 and is constrained to certain values depending on the scenario.   Your scenario, authorization code grant, is described in this section of the spec:  https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1

From the doc:

> grant_type
> REQUIRED.  Value MUST be set to "authorization_code".